# Devexpress xtragrid exporting to excel and keeping colored column headers

Tags: winforms, devexpress, export-to-excel, xtragrid

I use Devexpress V13.2.5. On my winforms project I have an xtragrid whose header colors I changed in the designer. However when I try to export the grid to excel

gridView1.ExportToXlsx(saveFileDialog1.FileName, exportOptions);

the header colors are not exported as well. Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: Check this http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/B97540

Comment: Unfortunately that sets the entire headers colour to a single colour. My grid header's columns are all different colours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply had to use the following line.

```
gridView1.OptionsPrint.UsePrintStyles = false;
```